# Ionic TypeScript Error (Property 'nav' does not exist on type 'HomePage')

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am following along this Ionic 2 tutorial and encountered problems. The problems are in the TypeScript (See the Picture). Here is the [video tutorial I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCE8DouJ8CY).

[image: the error message]

Here are the `src/pages/home/home.html`:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary *navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tasker
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngIf="!task.length">
      No Task Available
      <p> Click <ion-icon name="add"> to add task</ion-icon></p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="#t of tasks">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
        <ion-label>
          <h2 [ngClass]="t.status">{{t.task}}</h2>
          <p [ngClass]="t.priority">{{t.priority}}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options>

        <button primary><ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon>Edit</button>
        <button danger><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete</button>

      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>


  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

And the `src/pages/home/home.ts` Where the error occurred!:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  static get parameters(){
    return [[NavController]]
  }


  constructor(nav) {
    this.nav = nav;


    this.tasks = [
      {task:'test1', priority:'low', status:'pending'},
      {task:'test2', priority:'high', status:'done'},
      {task:'test3', priority:'normal', status:'pending'}
    ]
  }

}
```

Comment: try to do `constructor(private nav : NavController) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few typescript issues I see:

- You dont need `static get parameters` function at all.
- If you are injecting `NavController`, you can specify it like so:

  ```
  constructor(private nav:NavController) {
       //this.nav = nav; This is not required if you have set access 
       //specifier in constructor parameter
      // removed rest of code for brevity
  }
  ```
- Lastly, if you need to create a class variable in Typescript, you need to declare in the class.

  ```
  export class HomePage {
      tasks:any[]=[]
      // contstructor and other code
  }
  ```

Note the reference video seems to be using a much older version of Ionic. I suggest you find a recent tutorial video.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and another error occured saying that it cannot read some of the properties in the home.html file saying that they are undefined

Comment: you have to debug.. for example `task.length` probably should be `tasks.length`

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#t of tasks] in ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@24:22, what should i do now? sorry for being so needy...

Comment: you reaally need to find another tutorial or read angular official docs.. `*ngFor="let t of tasks"`. Your code may have a lot of changes as that tutorial is using beta version.. right now its ionic 3.x with angular 4.x

Comment: okay, any suggestions to learn more about ionic? Im a complete newbie in this.